# can't install iCloud Drive on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, icloud, ios-appstore, iphone

I just got an iPhone 7 from my job. Being more of an Android/Linux guy, I am actually very impressed by this device. One thing is very strange though: I can't find/acces the iCloud Drive app! When I ask Siri, it says that it isn't installed, and suggests that I install it. When I click the linked provided, there is the little icon with an cloud, but it is "toned out" in the colors, and nothing happens when I click it. I don't understand what I'm suppose to do about this.

The reason I need iCloud in the first place is to backup my phone (also "toned out" in the Settings → iCloud menu) and to use the "Just Press Record" app, which requires iCloud, and when I start the app it tells me I need to enable iCloud Drive first. Which I can't do.

Update: Under settings, there is an iCloud settings, which informs me that I have 5 GB storage and that Photos is using a little bit of it.

Under "Restrictions", it doesn't have anything registrered (which is the only possible cause provided by Just Press Records [support FAQ](http://www.openplanetsoftware.com/just-press-record/enable-icloud-in-settings.html).

I am logged into my apple account. When I log onto icloud.com, and select drive, I get this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1jxbhpn5ebr8o4/icloudtroubles.png?dl=0

...which tells me I should open the iCloud Drive app on my iOS device. So, back to square one, haha. Ever read the book Catch-22? Well, this is a Catch-22.

Thank you for your time,
Emil

Comment: Do you see an entry for iCloud in the `Settings` app?

Comment: Is the device managed centrally by your IT department? Are you logged in into iCloud/with your AppleID?

Comment: Hi, have updated my question with answers to your question to my question.

Comment: Under `Settings -> iCloud` do you see an entry for iCloud Drive?  Have you followed all the steps in [Apple's support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204025)?

Comment: The iCloud Drive App is available in the App Store. Have you looked there specifically for the app? [This page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204025) gives more info.

Comment: I found out, it *is* because of the settings/restrictions because of my phone being also a work phone. bummer .Thanks for your helpful suggestions though.

Comment: I don’t think so Emil.
I’m having the same problem and my phone isn’t a work phonee.
Have you found a sollution already?
Please let me know ! Grt
Kenzy

Comment: Well for me at least that was actually the case, look at the accepted answer to check whether your phone company has put in some restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this is restricted via MDM profiles. To check, open the settings app and inspect your profiles.

- Tap settings app
- Tap general
- Scroll content up if needed to see Profile (above Regulatory and below VPN)
- Tap in to each profile you have and inspect what it restricts.

If you have no profiles, I believe the profile entry is hidden so you might need to look for another answer if you don’t have a profile restricting this.

Comment: Yes that was it! Our it support told me this but forgot to answer it myself here. Thank you :)